# Log-Determinant Concavity Proof

Tags: convex-analysis, determinant

Can you please help me understand how he gets the equation marked by red from the above one ?

[image]

Comment: I presume that $\mathbf{S}^n$ is the set of positive definite symmetric matrices?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Note that when $A,B$ are square matrices of the same size, $\det AB=\det BA=\det A\det B~$. We use that here:
$$\begin{aligned}
\log\det(Z^{1/2}(I+tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})Z^{1/2}) &=
\log\det((I+tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})Z) \\
&= \log\left(\det(I+tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})\det Z\right) \\
&= \log\det(I+tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2}) + \log\det Z.
\end{aligned}$$
Let us define $\tilde{V} = Z^{-1/2}VZ^{1/2}$, and let $\tilde{V}=Q\Lambda Q^T$ be the Schur decomposition of $\tilde{V}$: $Q^TQ=QQ^T=I$ and $\Lambda=\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n)$.
$$\begin{aligned}
\log\det(I+t\tilde{V}) &= \log\det(I+tQ\Lambda Q^T) = \log\det(QQ^T+tQ\Lambda Q^T) \\
&= \log\det Q(I+t\Lambda)Q^T = \log\det Q^TQ(I+t\Lambda) \\
&= \log\det(I+t\Lambda) = \log \prod_i (1+t\lambda_i)\\
&= \sum_i \log(1+t\lambda_i).
\end{aligned}$$
The last two steps depend on the fact that $I+t\Lambda$ is diagonal, so its determinant is just the product of its diagonal elements.