# Linear objective function with determinant as a constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

So I have the following optimization problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{x:=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T\in\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\
\text{s.t.  }\quad \text{  det} G(x) = 0
\end{aligned}
$$

were $G(x) = I+\sum_{i=1}^n G_ix_i$ with $G_i\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ positive definite matrices.

This looks similar to some problems from "Convex Optimization" and "Linear Matrix Inequalities in System and Control Theory" by Stephen Boyd, such as the maxdet problem. However I have not been able to study the solution to such problem, even-tough I don't even have inequality constraints. I built the Lagrangian as
$$
\mathcal{L} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i+ \lambda\text{det} G(x)
$$
But when I take the gradient of $\mathcal{L}$ using Jacobi's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) it seems that I require $G(x)$ to be invertible. However, the constraint $\text{det} G(x)=0$ forbids this. I know that even if $G(x)^{-1}$ does not exists, its adjugate does exists. However, I don't see how this simplify the problem due to the expresion of $G(x)$. I expected to end up with some LMI condition or something like that.

Do suggest any other strategy to tackle this problem?

**EDIT**. Working a little bit more. Computing $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\mathcal{L} = 0$ gives this:
$$
\text{tr}(G(x)^*G_i) = -1/\lambda
$$
where $G(x)^*$ is the adjugate of $G(x)$. Or equivalently
$$
\text{tr}(G(x)^*G_i) = \text{tr}(G(x)^*G_j), \ \ \forall i,j \in \{1,\dots,n\}
$$

So, I end up with $n-1$ equations of the form $\text{tr}(G(x)^*(G_i-G_j))=0$ and the last equation is just $\text{det }G(x)=0$. Is that it? $n$ equations and $n$ variables and plug that into the computer? This is somewhat unsatisfying for me. I'm trying to find some expression for the solutions which might give more insight on how the solutions look like.

Do you see any improvement in this formulation?

**EDIT 2**. Someone suggested to replace the original problem with
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{x:=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T\in\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\
\text{s.t.}\ \ G(x) \succeq  0
\end{aligned}
$$

Which apparently is not necessarily equivalent to the original one but is stated as a classical LMI and is more suitable for me. Numerically I obtain that solutions to this new problem are solutions to the original one, but there might be some solutions missing I guess. **Would this be true in general? What do we lose by studying this problem instead?**

Comment: Maybe you can make use of the concavity of the logdet function on PSD matrices somehow? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192329/log-determinant-concavity-proof ... On the PSD cone $det(G) = 0$ is the same as infinitely many conditions of the form $log(det(G)) < -t$.

Comment: Hey! Yes, I think that idea is really nice! I'll have to think about it. Thanks!

Comment: I think the inequality goes the wrong way for getting convexity properties from logdet though -- the region where det is small is near the boundary of the cone (the boundary of the cone is the determinant zero stuff), so isn't convex.

Comment: To prove that you can replace the constraint with $G(x) \succeq 0$ you need to show that $G(x)$ for the optimal solution to the original problem does not have negative eigenvalues.

Comment: The derivative of the Lagrangian is not the problem: the determinant is just a high degree polynomial in $x$. The problem is solving the equation you end up with.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you @LinAlg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be formulated and solved as an optimization problem with linear objective and bilinear equality constraints, which can be solved to global optimality using Gurboi 9.x, or a general purpose branch and bound global optimizer.

The constraint `det(G(X)) = 0` is equivalent to G(X) being less than full rank, i.e., that one of the columns, the nth column to make it concrete, is a linear combination of all the other columns. Let $\alpha_i$, i=1,..,n-1 be additional optimization variables, which serve as the multiplier of the respective column.

The $n$ by $1$ vector constraint is

$$\Sigma_{i=1}^{i=n-1}\alpha_i\text{(ith column of G(x))} = \text{nth column of G(x)}$$ This involves product terms, $\alpha_i x_i$, hence is an $n$ by $1$ vector of bilinear equality constraints.

This might not be easy (fast) to solve, but it is easy to formulate.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Just one thing: when you say "that one of the columns,... is a linear combination of all the other columns." shouldn't that be that "at least" one of the columns is a linear combination of all other columns? Or why is it that rank $n-1$ for $G(x)$ is required instead of any other rank in 0,1\dots,n-2? Aren't we ignoring some possible solutions? By the way, this is a great change of paradigm on what I was thinking, and I use Gurobi a lot, so this suits me good. Thanks for answering! I'll think about this.

Comment: @Rodrigo Aldan The constraint in my formulation is equivalent to $\text{rank}(G) \le n-1$  I.e., accomplishes the "at least" in your comment.

Comment: You cannot just assume that the last column is a linear combination of the other ones, you would need to solve $n-1$ problems and pick the best solution among them.

Comment: if you pick bilinear optimization, you can avoid solving $n-1$ problems by using $G(x)y=0$ and $y^Te=1$.

Comment: What is $e$ in $y^Te=1$?